# How to use setPosition with a Point3D?

Tags: 3d, point, jsxgraph

How do I set the position of a Point3D? The Position of a 2D Point can be set with the method setPosition, followed by board.fullUpdate(). This does not seem to work with a Point3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v1.4.4 many functions for 3D handling are still missing, among them are setPosition3D and moveTo3D.

By the way, `point.moveTo([x,y], time);` is the preferred way to move 2D points. `setPosition()` is considered as low level. Nevertheless, `setPosition3D()` can be done by setting the array `p.D3.coords` of a 3D point `p`, followed by a board update:

```
var p = view.create('point3d', [1, 1, 2], { size: 5 });

// Coordinates given in the form [1, x, y, z]
p.D3.coords = [1, 1, 1, -2];
board.update();
```

The coords array of a 3D point has length 4 (as it contains homogeneous coordinates) and is of the form `[1, x, y, z]`.

See https://jsfiddle.net/wmsg2963/ for working example.